# All my datas in my store are nested in one row

Tags: extjs6

I m using admin-dashboard as template from folder extjs6.0.2 (http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard) and i followed the guide "Backend connectors" with "Direct and php mysql"(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/guides/backend_connectors/direct/mysql_php.html).

I m getting problems when i change the store into "Search results" in "User results" . I replaced the static store by an adapted version of the backend connector guide.

Router.php correctly provide data in json format but i have only one empty row in the grid panel user results.

Here is my store

```
Ext.define('Admin.store.import.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

alias: 'store.importusers',

fields: [
    {type: 'int', name: 'id'},
    {type: 'string', name: 'szNomUser'},
    {type: 'string', name: 'szPrenomUser'},
    {type : 'string', name: 'szLoginUser'},
    {type: 'string', name: 'szMailUser'}
],

proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    api: {
        read: 'QueryDatabase.getUsers'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
},
autoLoad : true
});
```

And the results from the query

```
{
"type": "rpc",
"tid": 1,
"action": "QueryDatabase",
"method": "getUsers",
"result": {
    "0": {
        "id": "2",
        "szNomUser": "ADMINISTRATEUR",
        "szPrenomUser": "Default",
        "szLoginUser": "admin",
        "szPassWordUser": "admin",
        "szProfilUser": "S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S",
        "nLangueUser": "1",
        "nRefIdStudioUser": "0",
        "szSuperviseurUser": "0",
        "szTelUser": "",
        "szFaxUser": "",
        "szMobileUser": "",
        "szMailUser": "martinbryan.eu@gmail.com",
        "tDateNaissanceUser": "2004-12-08",
        "bActifUser": "1",
        "szModeWeb": "0",
        "szSuperSuperviseurUser": "0",
        "szGroupUser": "T",
        "szActiviteUser": "1"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "18",
        "szNomUser": "DETTO",
        "szPrenomUser": "ERNEST",
        "szLoginUser": "ED",
        "szPassWordUser": "ED",
        "szProfilUser": "S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4S\u00a4N",
        "nLangueUser": "1",
        "nRefIdStudioUser": "0",
        "szSuperviseurUser": "0",
        "szTelUser": "",
        "szFaxUser": "",
        "szMobileUser": "",
        "szMailUser": "",
        "tDateNaissanceUser": "0000-00-00",
        "bActifUser": "0",
        "szModeWeb": "0",
        "szSuperSuperviseurUser": "0",
        "szGroupUser": "",
        "szActiviteUser": "1"
    }
}
}
```

and when i look into my gridpanel's store i have this tree :

store > data (length 1) > items (length 1)> [0] > data
in the last data i have ALL my datas and all fields are empty.
and this Exception
**Ext.data.Model#persistenceProperty** before the set of properties of the last data.

off course my gridpanel's column have correct dataIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well,

my datas weren't correctly formated, i looked at the **Direct specifications** from extjs 6 ([http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/guides/backend_connectors/direct/specification.html#backend_connectors-*-direct-*-specification_-_remoting_responses](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/guides/backend_connectors/direct/specification.html#backend_connectors-_-direct-_-specification_-_remoting_responses)) this is not clear if data must be json object or array of json object. and in my case, array of json object worked fine.

```
result — The data returned by the Method. 
MUST be present in the Response object, 
but MAY be null for Methods that do not return any data.


{
"type": "rpc",
"tid": 1,
"action": "QueryDatabase",
"method": "getUsers",
"result": [{
    "nIdUser": "2",
    "szNomUser": "ADMINISTRATEUR",
    "szPrenomUser": "Default",
    "szMailUser": "martinbryan.eu@gmail.com",
    "szLoginUser": "admin"
}, {
    "nIdUser": "18",
    "szNomUser": "DETTO",
    "szPrenomUser": "ERNEST",
    "szMailUser": "",
    "szLoginUser": "ED"
}]
}
```